# Canadian PR, US LPR flying to Canada with expired PR card and valid greencard

Tags: usa, airlines, canadian-permanent-residents

My situation is as follows

- I have Valid Canadian PR status
- My Canadian PR card has expired
- I have valid US LPR status
- My greencard is valid
- I reside in the US

I am sure I meet the Residency Obligations. I have had no issues crossing the border into Canada by land in the last several months. However, this time I am planning to fly to Canada.

I am not worried about the CBSA check on landing in Canada. I am worried about being denied boarding on the flight?

Is there any risk of that happening?

Comment: What passport will be using? Generally, if you have a valid passport and a valid green card, you are fine. Your Canadian PR status doesn't really matter.

Comment: How can you possibly be a PR in two countries? AFAIK at least in the US your claim to be a PR in Canada can be considered as not being a LPR in the US, you may end up in front of an immigration judge if the USCIS/ICE come to know of this.

Comment: @Hilmar, I have an Indian passport

Comment: @littleadv There is no law that prevents me from being a PR in both country. The condition of validity of my PR status is me fulfilling the residency obligations in both countries which I am doing. The purpose of this trip to Canada is to take the citizenship oath after which I would a PR of only US making it easier to maintain my residency obligation here. Both countries are aware of my current residency status in the other.

Comment: One might argue that maintaining a PR status in Canada is showing that you're "Moving to another country and intending to live there permanently;", similarly acquiring LPR status in the US shows that to Canada. I'm sure, of course, that you know what you're doing, but I'm just saying that it may catch up with you in the most inconvenient time. In the US there's no statute of limitations on immigration fraud, I'm assuming that Canada has none either.

Comment: Since your PR card has expired, Canada’s entry rules say you need a permanent resident travel document to board a flight https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/application/application-forms-guides/guide-5529-applying-permanent-resident-travel-document.html

Comment: @Bellarina: "me fulfilling the residency obligations in both countries which I am doing" There are no objective "residency obligations" for the US. Abandonment of US residence is a subjective determination that can consider many factors.

Comment: @user102008 you are right.

Answer (score 2):

As lawful permanent residents of the United States no longer (as of April 26, 2022) need a prior authorization (ETA) before travelling to Canada by air, only a valid green card **and** a valid passport or travel document are required before boarding the plane (passport is absolutely necessary due to secure flight regulations in Canada), after the arrival of which you may seek entry as permanent resident of Canada with supporting evidences (e.g. expired PR card).

You do not have to present evidence of your status in Canada to the airlines.

However, there have been reports, as recent as July 2023, that some non-Canadian airlines (or their contracted ground staff) are still not familiar with the rule changes in Canada and may insist on an ETA due to outdated information in their system or memory. You have to insist politely but firmly with the evidence from official Canadian government website (https://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=1053&top=16) as well as possibly from the airlines' website (e.g. for United: https://www.united.com/ual/en/us/fly/travel/destination/international.html "U.S. citizens and permanent residents of the U.S. do not need an eTA or a visa.").

Comment: Thanks @xbgtng. Do you know if the airline is able to know my status as Canadian PR by scanning my passport or entering its info into a system? And if they come to know of my PR status would that trigger the need for me to produce a valid PR card?

Comment: @Bellarina At the moment no. Additionally, there is no requirement for a Canadian permanent resident to fly to or enter Canada with a permanent resident card.